# Adding to a given XML the XSLT stylesheet declaration with perl + LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, stylesheet, xml-libxml

Premise: I come from C++ and I'm pretty noob at Perl.
I'm trying to add a stylesheet declaration to a given `.xml` file. The `.xml` file is created by a third part and downloaded aside; we are not questioning correctness nor well-formedness of the XML. We also can't know if the XML in the file is indented or in one-row.

Not being able to manipulate the file neatly only with Perl, I took XML::LibXML but I'm still stuck. This is so far what I've done.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $path = './file.xml';

my $fxml = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0','utf-8');
my $pi = $fxml->createPI("xml-stylesheet");
$pi->setData(type=>'text/xsl', href=>'trasf.xsl');
$fxml->appendChild($pi);

$XML::LibXML::skipXMLDeclaration = 1;
my $docwodecl = XML::LibXML::Document->new;
$docwodecl = $doc->toString;

open my $out_fh, '>', $path;
print {$out_fh} $final_xml.$docwodecl;
close $out_fh;
```

With this I only get the XML without the initial declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` and the utf-8 characters are all messed up.
I've tried to use something like this

```
$fxml->setDocumentElement($doc);
$fxml->toFile($path);
```

but it doesn't work.
There's some method i could use to accomplish my (after all pretty simple) goal? I've looked in the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0004/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod) but I can't find anything useful.

#### EDIT

The stylesheet declaration have to be after the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and before the actual XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your fxml initialisation to

```
my $fxml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $path);
```

You are not loading the original file anywhere.

### Update

You can insert the node *before* the root element by using `insertBefore`:

```
my $path = '1.xml';
my $fxml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $path);
my $pi   = $fxml->createPI('xml-stylesheet');
$pi->setData(type => 'text/xsl', href => 'trasf.xsl');
$fxml->insertBefore($pi, $fxml->documentElement);
```

Comment: I was stuck putting the stylesheet declaration exactly after the `<?xml ?>` declaration and before the root element. Putting it at the bottom of the XML solved the whole thing! `:-)`

Comment: I Just discovered that the stylesheet declaration **needs** to be putted on the top, between the xml declatarion and the actual XML. So your solution is not the final...

Comment: By the way, where I can find a good reference for useful methods like that other than [cpan.org](http://cpan.org)? I read now that `insertBefore` is part of `XML::GDOME`, but without knowing I would never start using it.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I don't have enough reputation to give further +1